# No carga localhost:81, Inconvenientes con el cambio de puerto 80 a 81

Tags: php, xampp

Amigos, cambié la configuración del puerto localhost:80 a localhost:81
en los siguientes archivos:
httpd.conf:
Listen 81
ServerName localhost:81

En la configuración (config) en xampp> en Services and port services> donde dice main port a 81, pero cuando reinicio y coloco localhost no me carga nada, reinicié la PC y nada tampoco, ¿que puede ser?

Me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya intentaste acceder de esta forma: **localhost:num_puerto** ?

Comment: Gracias por responder, si, funciona localhost:81, pero ¿porqué no funciona solamente localhost?

Answer (score 2):

Cómo ya te había mencionado en los comentarios podrás acceder al localhost.

De esta forma:

> http://localhost:81

Esto es debido a que has cambiado el número de puerto para acceder al servidor local, ya que por default está asignado con el puerto 80.
Así que cada vez que realices un cambio de puerto vas a tener que acceder con el número de puerto que colocaste.

Comment: ¿existe una manera de colocar solo localhost sin colocar el puerto 81?

Comment: Claro al instalar XAMPP por primera vez e iniciar podrás acceder al servidor local solamente colocando  http://localhost , la configuración hiciste solamente se hace cuando no puedes acceder a servidor ya que otros programas que tienes instalado estén utilizando el mismo puerto.

Answer (score 1):

Amigos, nada como encontrar la respuesta uno mismo, bueno, al menos esta es una solucion. debido a que el localhost el modificado bajo otro puerto, en este caso localhost:81, si les parece tan molesto como a mi tener que colocar :81 a todo existe una manera de evitarnos eso ¿como? de esta forma:

Primero entramos a Panel de Control> Centro de redes y recursos compartidos (si usas W10, W8.1 o W7).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues hacemos click en Conexiones>Configuracion de LAN:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego marcamos la casilla de usar un proxy para LAN y en Opciones Avanzadas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y es justamente aqui en donde colocamos el localhost ó colocamos la ip local 127.0.0.1 con el puerto 81.
Si lo colocamos en los demas protocolos no nos funcionará el internet, al menos eso me pasó a mí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al menos ya me funciona sin tener que colocar localhost:81 <-este fastidio 
Aunque funciona de igual manera colocando :81 pero es molesto de verdad.
Espero que les sirva de ayuda.

Extra: pueden hacer todo esto desde la configuración de un navegador, para no interferir en todos los demás navegadores, así que si te gusta un navegador en particular puedes usar otro colocándole la dirección proxy localhost:81/127.0.0.1:81 para que no tengas que cambiar a cada rato, aunque ya todas las paginas WEB usan protocolo HTTPS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Pues habiendo cambiado en los dos sitios me parece raro que no te funcione.
En el archivo httpd.conf hay tres sitios en los que hay que cambiarlo:
Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80

Comment: Gracias por responder, justamente ya cambié los 3 valores a :81 y nada, me sale la imagen de arriba.